# View shopping cart function not returning proper values

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object

So my goal is to create a psuedo shopping cart with vanilla JS for a coding assignment and one of the goals is to create a viewCart() function that does not accept any arguments.

Instructions: It should loop over every item in your cart, printing out the contents as one long, coherent statement in this format: In your cart, you have bananas at $17, pancake batter at $5, and eggs at $49.

Conditions:

- If the cart is empty, the function should instead print out: Your
  shopping cart is empty.
- 1 item sample output: In your cart, you have bananas at $17.
- 2 items — In your cart, you have bananas at $17 and pancake batter at
  $5.
- 3+ items — In your cart, you have bananas at $17, pancake batter at
  $5, and eggs at $49.

So far I have successfully completed the first two conditions and have almost completed the third one. However, my function will return something like this:

In your cart, you have bananas at $17, **and**  pancake batter at $5eggs at $49.

Instead of:

In your cart, you have bananas at $17, pancake batter at $5, and eggs at $49.

I added some comments in the function to help you guys debug if you need it.

```
  var cart = [];

    function getCart() {
     return cart;
    }

    function setCart(c) {
      cart = c;
      return cart;
    }


    function addToCart(itemName) {
     var object = {[itemName]: Math.floor(Math.random(1,100) * 100)};
     cart.push(object);
     console.log(`${itemName} has been added to your cart`);
     return cart;
    }



 function viewCarted() {
  if(!cart.length) {
    console.log('Your shopping cart is empty.');
  }
  else {
    var items = [];
    // for loop to iterate over objects in cart
    for(var i=0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      // another for loop to iterate over the object's keys
      for(var item in cart[i]) {
        // adding the key and value into the items array
        items.push(item + " at $" + cart[i][item]);
      }
    }
    //  checking if items array length is equal to 2
    // if it is, then it'll add an "and" after the first comma and finish the function
    // if not then output will be: In your cart, you have banana at $77.
    if(items.length == 2) {
      return(`In your cart, you have ${items.join(" and ") + "."}`);
    } 
    // otherwise if there is three or more items in the cart then these conditions will activate
    else {
      // another for loop to iterate over the cart array
      for(var x=0; x < cart.length; x++) {
        // testing to see the indexes: 0,1,2
        console.log(x)
        // condition to see if it isn't the last item in cart
        if(x+1 != cart.length) {
           console.log(`In your cart, you have ${items.join(", ") + "."}`);
        } 
        // condition if it is the last item
        else {
          const mostItems = items.slice(0, -1);
          const lastItem = items.slice(-1)[ 0 ];
          console.log(`In your cart, you have ${mostItems.join(", and ")}${lastItem}.`);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

  addToCart("banana")
  addToCart("a")
  addToCart("b")
  viewCarted();
```

Output:

```
0
In your cart, you have banana at $40, a at $62, b at $75.
1
In your cart, you have banana at $40, a at $62, b at $75.
2
In your cart, you have banana at $40, and a at $62b at $75.
```

Comment: Don't put in a special case for only 2 items. Instead, make it a special case for the *last 2* items.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining *all* the items with `, and ...` instead of just the last one in your last conditional.

Instead, you can split them into "all - 1" and "last" like this:

```
    else {
       const mostItems = items.slice(0, -1);
       const lastItem = items.slice(-1)[ 0 ];
       console.log(`In your cart, you have ${mostItems.join(", and ")}${lastItem}.`);
    }
```

Place this in the following `else`:

```
    // condition to see if it isn't the last item in cart
    if(x+1 != cart.length) {
       console.log(`In your cart, you have ${items.join(", ") + "."}`);
    } 
    // condition if it is the last item
    else {
       // new stuff goes here:


       // OLD STUFF
       // console.log(`In your cart, you have ${items.join(", and ") + "."}`);
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry where would i put that else statement? I tried putting it in after if(items.length == 2) but I still got the same type of output as last time

Comment: I'm getting the following output:                                                                     0
In your cart, you have banana at $40, a at $62, b at $75.
1
In your cart, you have banana at $40, a at $62, b at $75.
2
In your cart, you have banana at $40, and a at $62b at $75.                                                                                                                                                     which isn't really correct since the and comes after the 2nd comma, not the last, and there is no space after $62